# Cabal install http-conduit-browser

Tags: haskell, cabal, http-conduit

It's possible this is such a struggle because I'm on Windows... My latest attempt to get out of Cabal Hell, using the Git Bash:

```
$ rm -R ~/AppData/Roaming/ghc ~/AppData/Roaming/cabal
$ cabal update
$ cabal install cabal-install
$ cabal install http-conduit-browser
```

Which results in:

```
Failed to install http-conduit-1.9.6
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\http-conduit-1.9.6.log ):
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Read Cookie)

Network\HTTP\Conduit\Types.hs:239:19:
    No instance for (Show UTCTime)
      arising from the third field of `Cookie' (type `UTCTime')
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Show Cookie)
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
http-conduit-1.9.6 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
http-conduit-browser-1.9.0.2 depends on http-conduit-1.9.6 which failed to
install.
```

Attempting to just install `http-conduit` works fine, but I can't seem to get `http-conduit-browser` installed at all. If this can't work, are there any other libraries out there? I've also tried `shpider` but it won't work because of the `curl` library.

Comment: Can you post the entire log `C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\http-conduit-1.9.6.log`?

Comment: I took the suggestion from the answer below and used Wreq instead. I would post the log but I've since nuked my cabal. If anyone else runs into the same problem Wreq was pretty easy to set up and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github page for http-conduit-browser [(link)](https://github.com/exbb2/http-conduit-browser) recommends that you use wreq [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq) instead.

If you want to use http-conduit-browser here's the trick to getting http-conduit-1.9.6 to build:

1. cabal get http-conduit-1.9.6
2. cd http-conduit-1.9.6
3. modify Network/HTTP/Conduit/Types.hs according to this SO answer: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27136811/866915) [replace import Data.Time.Clock with import Data.Time]
4. cabal install

Now you should be able to build http-conduit-browser.